# Multiple bars in one bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to 'combine' these plots, in the same bar chart.
[image: bar plot 1]
[image: bar plot 2]
[image: bar plot 3]

Here is the code with which I generated these graphics

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (13,6)

def generate_histogram(distribucion):
    values = list(distribucion.values())
    intensities = list(distribucion.keys())

    # plotting configuration
    figure = plt.figure()
    axes = figure.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    histogram = axes.bar(intensities,values,width=14)
    plt.xticks(intensities,intensities)

    # title and label
    axes.set_title('Intensity distribution')
    axes.set_xlabel('Intensity (0 to 255)')
    axes.set_ylabel('Probability')

    # fix scale
    plt.ylim(0, 0.55)
    plt.autoscale(False)

    # function that make the labels
    def autolabel(rects):
        """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
        for rect in rects:
            height = round((float)(rect.get_height()),4)
            axes.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                        xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                        xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                        textcoords="offset points",
                        ha='center', va='bottom',fontsize=10)

    # generate autolabels
    autolabel(histogram)

    # show graph
    plt.show()

generate_histogram(distribution_1)
generate_histogram(distribution_2)
generate_histogram(distribution_3)
```

here is the data that I'm using

```
distribution_1 = {221: 0.360416255051639, 238: 0.19880422092501124, 204: 0.08321239335428827, 187: 0.05222900763358779, 170: 0.048701841041760216, 153: 0.04666771441400988, 136: 0.04238796587337225, 119: 0.03527929950606197, 255: 0.008626852267624607, 102: 0.029128423888639426, 85: 0.025297709923664122, 68: 0.025161652447238437, 51: 0.02414683430624158, 34: 0.015194881005837449, 17: 0.004271216883700045, 0: 0.00047373147732375395}
distribution_2 = {221: 0.4157265379434216, 238: 0.19262191288729233, 204: 0.07130848675348002, 187: 0.04102649303996408, 170: 0.041006286484059275, 153: 0.04099775482712169, 136: 0.03805253704535249, 119: 0.03213920071845532, 102: 0.0272240682532555, 255: 0.007630893578805568, 85: 0.024198473282442748, 68: 0.024454422990570275, 51: 0.023817691962281097, 34: 0.015106870229007634, 17: 0.004220925011225864, 0: 0.00046744499326448137}
distribution_3 = {255: 0.4824301751234845, 221: 0.0699272563987427, 187: 0.06918679838347552, 170: 0.050990121239335426, 153: 0.04777503367759318, 238: 0.024907049842837897, 136: 0.04586124831612034, 119: 0.041772339470139204, 102: 0.034856757970363715, 85: 0.022533453075886844, 68: 0.03175348001796138, 51: 0.025796587337224966, 34: 0.02501930848675348, 17: 0.015535698248765155, 0: 0.008881903906600808, 204: 0.002772788504714863}
```

I want something like this with the label turn 90 degree so they don't overlap

[image: an example of what i want]

Comment: Could you share the data that you used?

Comment: Sorry the delay. I already edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should be outside of the other one so it's not being defined each time.

```
# function that make the labels
def autolabel(rects,axes):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = round((float)(rect.get_height()),4)
        axes.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom',fontsize=10,rotation=90)
```

Then you have to offset two sets of the x values by the width of the bars:

1. the first set gets offset -.1 (to the left)
2. the second set doesn't get offset
3. the third set gets offset +.1 (to the right)

```
def generate_histogram(distribucion,axes=None,figure=None,h_adjustment=None):
    values = list(distribucion.values())
    intensities = list(distribucion.keys())
    width = .1

    # plotting configuration
    if not figure:
        figure = plt.figure(figsize=(13,6))
        axes = figure.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    histogram = axes.bar([intensity + h_adjustment 
                          for intensity in intensities],values,width)
    #plt.xticks(intensities,intensities)

    # title and label
    axes.set_title('Intensity distribution')
    axes.set_xlabel('Intensity (0 to 255)')
    axes.set_ylabel('Probability')

    # fix scale
    plt.ylim(0, 0.55)
    plt.autoscale(False)

    # generate autolabels
    autolabel(histogram,axes)

    return figure, axes
```

Call the function like this:

```
a = {8:.5,7:.2,10:.11,6:.3}
figure,axes = generate_histogram(a,h_adjustment=-.1) 
b = {10:.35,7:.23,8:.25,6:.4}
figure,axes = generate_histogram(b,figure=figure,axes=axes,h_adjustment=0)
c = {10:.25,8:.44,9:.5,6:.45}
generate_histogram(c,figure=figure,axes=axes,h_adjustment=.1)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried this code and print a tiny image. I don't know why

Comment: @Mattii: I updated the code please try it again. Thanks.

Comment: Still the same. maybe it's has to do with google colab?